# Error while calling path of file in react native.

Tags: reactjs, react-native, routes, react-navigation

I decided to nest every react native component & screen I have inside its own specified sub folder. The problem is when I import a react native component in another file its gives me this error: [ios Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiDGx.png) and I'm importing everything the right away. I checked the path multiple times to make sure everything is correct. Moreover, in my navigation file I use the same file path & everything works fine. This how my folders and subfolders are nested under the src file: [structure of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkSWY.png). And this is my navigation file(everything gets imported correctly in this file, i'm guessing because its outside the src file):

```html
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

import WelcomeScreen from './src/components/screens/WelcomeScreen/WelcomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './src/components/screens/ProfileScreen/ProfileScreen';
import RegistrationScreen from './src/components/screens/RegistrationScreen/RegistrationScreen';
import RecieveMenuScreen from './src/components/screens/RecieveMenuScreen/RecieveMenuScreen';
import SendDetailsScreen from './src/components/screens/SendDetailsScreen/SendDetailsScreen';
import SendAddressScreen from './src/components/screens/SendAddressScreen/SendAddressScreen';
import SendShipmentScreen from './src/components/screens/SendShipmentScreen/SendShipmentScreen';
import SendOverviewScreen from './src/components/screens/SendOverviewScreen/SendOverviewScreen';
import SendReceiptScreen from './src/components/screens/SendReceiptScreen/SendReceiptScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './src/components/screens/SettingsScreen/SettingsScreen';

const WelcomeStack = createStackNavigator({
 Welcome: {
  screen: WelcomeScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
   header: null
  }
 }
});

const SendStack = createStackNavigator({
 SendDetails: {
  screen: SendDetailsScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
   headerTitle: 'Enter Details'
  }
 },
 SendAddress: {
  screen: SendAddressScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
   headerTitle: 'Shipment Address'
  }
 },
 SendShipment: {
  screen: SendShipmentScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
   headerTitle: 'Send Shipment'
  }
 },
 SendOverview: {
  screen: SendOverviewScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
   headerTitle: 'Shipment Overview'
  }
 },
 SendReceipt: {
  screen: SendReceiptScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
   headerTitle: 'Shipment Details'
  }
 }
});

const RecieveStack = createStackNavigator({
 RecieveMenu: {
  screen: RecieveMenuScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
   headerTitle: 'Incoming Shipments'
  }
 }
});

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
 Profile: {
  screen: ProfileScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
   headerTitle: 'Profile'
  }
 }
});

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
 Settings: {
  screen: SettingsScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
   headerTitle: 'Settings'
  }
 }
});

export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
 Recieve: {
  screen: RecieveStack,
  navigationOptions: {
   tabBarLabel: 'Recieve',
   tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="list" size={35} color={tintColor} />
  }
 },
 Send: {
  screen: SendStack,
  navigationOptions: {
   tabBarLabel: 'Send',
   tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="account-circle" size={35} color={tintColor} />
  }
 },
 Profile: {
  screen: ProfileStack,
  navigationOptions: {
   tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
   tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="account-circle" size={35} color={tintColor} />
  }
 },
 View: {
  screen: SettingsStack,
  navigationOptions: {
   tabBarLabel: 'View',
   tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="account-circle" size={35} color={tintColor} />
  }
 }
});

export const Routes = createStackNavigator({
 Welcome: {
  screen: WelcomeStack,
  navigationOptions: {
   header: null
  }
 },
 Registration: {
  screen: RegistrationScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
   headerTitle: 'Registration'
  }
 },
 Profile: {
  screen: Tabs,
  navigationOptions: {
   header: null
  }
 }
});
```

I'm probably doing something wrong when I import a file in another file that is also under the src folder, but I need someone to point to me exactly what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: I think you don't understand how Module Resolution works. Kindly google search about this topic, you will get a lot of details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well navigating with relative paths is not that hard :)

so if you want to import something e.G. 'ProfileScreen' + 'BarCode' to WelcomeScreen

your File should look like this:

#### ./src/components/screens/WelcomeScreen/WelcomeScreen.js'

```
import BarCode from './../../common/BarCode/BarCode';
import ProfileScreen from './../ProfileScreen/ProfileScreen';
```

{...}

**"./.."** = one layer upwards (like **"cd .."**)

soo you always start at the location of the File you are importing to
(in this Case **'./src/components/screens/WelcomeScreen/WelcomeScreen.js'**)

so you start at './src/components/screens/WelcomeScreen/'

by doing **"./../../"** you get to **'./src/components/'**

and from here you have to go to **'./common/BarCode/'** where **'BarCode.js'** lies

shortened up and put all thogether you end at:

**'./../../common/BarCode/BarCode'**